# Get a limit on arrays (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, limit

I've a problem with set a limit into my own lightbox for a gallery

```
    <script>


var imagenumber = 0;

    function btnleft(){
        load = imagenumber-=1;
        document.getElementById('lightboxcontent').innerHTML=imagelist[load];

        }

function btnright(){
    load = imagenumber+=1;
    if (load==undefined){load=imagenumber-=1}
    document.getElementById('lightboxcontent').innerHTML=imagelist[load];
    }
</script>
```

Then the array

```
var imagelist=new Array(); // regular array (add an optional integer
imagelist[0]="image1.jpg";       // argument to control array's size)
imagelist[1]="image2.jpg";
imagelist[2]="image3.jpg";
```

When I click more then 3 times on the next button I got the error-message "undefined".
How should I do to get a limit on my arrays?

Comment: You mean the `array.length` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with

```
 function btnleft(){
    var load = imagelist[imagenumber-=1];
    if (load) // imagenumber in array boundaries
        document.getElementById('lightboxcontent').innerHTML = load;
    else
        imagenumber = 0;
 }
 function btnright(){
    var load = imagelist[imagenumber+=1];
    if (load) // imagenumber in array boundaries
        document.getElementById('lightboxcontent').innerHTML = load;
    else
        imagenumber = imagelist.length-1;
 }
```

Yet, `Array`s in Javascript have no limited size, they are more like (infinite) lists. You can hardly set a limit on their length - espcially not with the [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), whose number argument is just for initialisation purposes.

You can use the [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of an array to check whether your index is in the array boundaries: `i >= 0 && i < arr.length`. My code just checks whether there is an item at that index (as your second function seems to intend, too) and resets the index otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that clicking on the "next button" calls the `btnright()` function.

If that is the case then you are testing the wrong value for `undefined`.  You could rewrite your function as:

```
function btnright(){
  load = imagenumber += 1;
  // Test the value at the index of the array, not your index variable.
  if (imagelist[load] === undefined) {
    load = imagenumber-= 1;
  }
  document.getElementById('lightboxcontent').innerHTML = imagelist[load];
}
```

Stylistically this is still no the best.  Your `load` variable is not required since its value always duplicates `imagenumber`.  You could refactor the function such:

```
function btnright() {
  // If we have a new array value do something.
  if (imagelist[imagenumber + 1] !== undefined) {
    // Increment the index and load the new image.
    document.getElementById('lightboxcontent').innerHTML = imagelist[++imagenumber];
  }
}

function btnleft() {
  // If we're not on the first image do something.
  if (imagenumber !== 0) {
    // Decrement the index and load the new image.
    document.getElementById('lightboxcontent').innerHTML = imagelist[--imagenumber];
  }
}
```